# Koma-script, change chapter appearance (how to add a circle and horizontal ruler?)

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script, chapters

I'd like to get the chapter names formatted as shown below:

[image]

with a horizontal ruler between the circle and Chapter name, for both numbered and non-numbered chapters (I work with the `chapterprefix=on` option, so I'd like not to loose the "Chapter" word before chapter no.)

The problems are:

1. Placing a horizontal ruler.
2. Having the title at the same line as "CHAPTER {number}."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; this will work as expected with both numbered and unnumbered chapters; taking into account the comments, I've replaced the initial definition of the circle with `\CIRCLE` from the `wasysym` package:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\CIRCLE\vskip6pt\titlerule[1pt]\vskip9pt\chaptertitlename~\thechapter.}
  {0.5em}{}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\CIRCLE\vskip6pt\titlerule[1pt]\vskip9pt}
  {0pc}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\chapter*{Test Unnumbered Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Some images of the output showing a numbered and an unnumbered chapter:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot. Actually this solution is something I can fully understand and modify, while the first one seemed for me a kind of magic (although it worked pretty good for numbered chapters too).

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Tikz consumes a lot of time while compiling. Wouldn't it be better to include a circle as as a graphic?

Comment: @Keks Dose - I actually used the wasysym-version of circle with the `\CIRCLE` command in math mode.

Comment: @KeksDose: you're right. I've changed the code; the new version doesn't use TikZ but `\CIRCLE` from `wasysym` as **Alexandre** suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion for newer KOMA-Script versions:

You do not want an extra prefix line for the chapter name and number. So do not use option `chapterprefix=on`. You can redefine `\chapterformat` to insert the prefix `\chaptername` (or `\appendixname`). Then you can redefine `\chapterlinesformat` to insert the dot and the rule:

```
\documentclass[
  numbers=endperiod,% dot at the end of numbers
]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{wasysym}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% chapter name as prefix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
\Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
  {\CIRCLE\\*\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\vskip9pt}{}% insert dot and rule before chapter titles
\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\chapter*{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution to this one that makes use of rulers in the headers, what I am interested in is to display the title of each chapter in 2 lines, the first one containing the word "Chapter" and the number, then a ruler and in the bottom line the name of the chapter in question. 

From KOMA Script of course, however, I don't quite understand your solution, is there any section of the documentation that you recommend me to read about it?

Comment: @Aradnix Use option `chapterprefix=on`, remove the redefinitions of  `\chapterformat` and `\chapterlinesformat`. Redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` (see the documentation for this macro) and add `\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter}`. Should there be a ruler too, even if a chapter is not numbered? Maybe you have to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubles to understand what you mean by "circle symbol, 20 pt" did you mean radius or diameter? Now then... i wrote a piece of code which i would consider as a bit dangerous (maybe `titlesec` provides a more user-spaceish way). This takes one of KOMA´s basic definitions and alter it to fit your requirements. I had troubles with chaptermark as well so i used this definition. This is of course not tested adequately but i believe it should work in any situation.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
 \renewcommand*{\@@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip
  {%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \if@chapterprefix
      \let\@tempa\raggedsection
    \else
      \let\@tempa\@hangfrom
    \fi
    \@tempa{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
        \if@mainmatter
          \if@chapterprefix
            \expandafter\size@chapterprefix
          \else
            \expandafter\size@chapter
          \fi
          {\tikz\fill circle (20pt) ; \rule[.75\baselineskip]{5cm}  {1pt}}%insted of chaptermark 
          \if@chapterprefix
            \size@chapterprefix{}\endgraf\nobreak\vskip.5\baselineskip%               \chapapp\enskip \thechapter.\enskip
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    {\raggedsection \interlinepenalty \@M \size@chapter{#1}\par}}%
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{text}
    Test text 
  \section{text}
    Test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!That actually did a trick with the numbered chapters, with slight modifications: http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120416/Ju6wsBrZ.jpg , although the circle/horiz. line do not apper after \chapter*