# Chapter with background images in KOMA-Script

Tags: graphics, chapters, koma-script

I would like to have a chapter design like

[image]

So in the Box of the title, should be an image in the background and above the number of the chapter.

The packages I'm using so far, are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{scrbook} %{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
```

**Update:**
by substituting the ducks through:

```
\chapternumberbackground{\begin{tikzpicture}\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{logo.pdf}\end{tikzpicture}}
```

I get an division by 0 error ... why? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you seen the show case https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoirchapterstyles?lang=en ?

Comment: Which class do you intend to use? Please provide at least some code! This site is not a we-do-it-for-you-service! Show what you got so far (even if it's not much) and we'll most likely be glad to help. I won't touch the question as it is now!

Comment: what template (.cls) file you are using?

Comment: Fancy chapter package does not really help me, as it does not have the desired layout.

Comment: @LatexNoob but you could create the desired layout with it (or without it; or with another package -- who knows, you don't tell us which class you use nor which other packages).

Comment: You also need to check the requirements for your university.  They may even provide/require a LaTeX cls file.

Comment: @LatexNoob you should edit your question to include this code.

Comment: A few examples how to modify scrbook chapters: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150923/customizing-chapter-style-in-scrbook  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230635/formatting-and-styling-of-headers-using-titlesec-in-scrbook-class

Comment: Or more recent: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388585, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387988, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246411, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376737, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375401

Comment: If you have a question to an already given answer please leave a comment below the answer or ask a following-up question instead of modify your question. However I've added information on how to use `\includegraphics` to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can do a lot of things with KOMA-Script's chapter headings, if you redefine `\chapterformat` and `\chapterlinesformat` or `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`. If I interpret your question as

### How to use ducks in chapter headings of KOMA-Script?

I could, e.g, do:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}% need scalable font
\usepackage{tikzducks}% essential to use ducks
\usepackage{blindtext}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  font=\normalfont\huge\scshape,
  prefixfont=\Large,
  innerskip=0pt
]{chapter}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft

\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{#3}{%
    \rule{.333\linewidth}{1pt} #2%
    \parbox[b][\dimexpr .2\linewidth-\dp\strutbox-\baselineskip]{.78\linewidth}{%
      \raggedchapter\strut\ignorespaces #3%
    }\hfill
    \makebox[.2\linewidth][r]{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{1pt}}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{%
    \chapapp\enskip
    \usekomafont{chapter}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr -.2\linewidth+\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
%      \frame{%
        \resizebox*{.2\linewidth}{.2\linewidth}{%
          \currentchapternumberbackground
        }%
%      }%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \parbox{.2\linewidth}{%
          \centering
          \fontsize{.75\linewidth}{\linewidth}\selectfont
          \raisebox{.75\linewidth}{\color{gray!50!red!50}\thechapter}\par
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \thechapter\autodot\enskip
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\chapternumberbackground}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\currentchapternumberbackground}{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\currentchapternumberbackground}{%
  {\color{red!50}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapternumberbackground{\begin{tikzpicture}\duck\end{tikzpicture}}
\chapter{Chapter Name}
\blindtext

\chapternumberbackground{\begin{tikzpicture}\duck[longhair=teal]\end{tikzpicture}}
\chapter{Another Chapter Name}
\blindtext

\chapternumberbackground{\begin{tikzpicture}\duck[crazyhair=green,eyebrow=blue]\end{tikzpicture}}
\chapter{Once more a Longer Chapter Name}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: First chapter]

[image: Second chapter]

[image: Third chapter]

For more information about `\RedeclareSectionCommand`, `\chapterformat` and `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` see the [KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) also [available in German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf). And don't forget the famous information about [using ducks in TikZ](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzducks/tikzducks-doc.pdf).

And yes, instead of the `tikzpicture` with the `\duck` commands, you can use a `\includegraphics` command like:

```
\chapternumberbackground{\includegraphics[page=54,trim=30 0 30 0,clip]{example-image-duck}}
```

Note, the `\resizebox` in the code of the full example would resize such an external image too. So if you want images in another size, you have to change or remove the `\resizebox`.

Comment: `tikzducks` is *not* for demo only :)

Comment: @Skillmon Your absolutely right. Fixed. ;-)

Comment: I WILL USE THIS FOR MY THESIS

Comment: +1 for the ducks! In the new package version, there will be a graduate duck -> perfect for a phd thesis! https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0ogv.png (and the bounding box size will also be fixed so the ducks don't get distorted)

Comment: @samcarter Very nice!

Comment: Another one has joined the Duck Side of the Force! <3 <3 <3

Comment: @Schweinebacke: thank you very much for all your effort! By putting the required image in to the chapter instead of the duck the image shift right... but i going to try to fix it with \hspace

Comment: You prevent me from many hours or even days of despair!